# Combine properties values from a custom List with LINQ

Tags: linq, list

Lets assume I have a list of Persons, in the List I have the following objects:

```
Person = { ID= 1, State="CA"}
Person = { ID= 2, State="PA"}
Person = { ID= 1, State="NY"}
Person = { ID= 1, State="OH"}
Person = { ID= 3, State="FL"}
Person = { ID= 2, State="KC"}
```

How do I get a new List Where I can have new Persons by ID only once and if repeated get the State value and put it in the new Person object separated by comma. For example the new List will be

```
Person = { ID= 1, State="CA,NY,OH"}
Person = { ID= 2, State="PA,KC"}
Person = { ID= 3, State="FL"}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the extension method version

```
  var persons = Person.GroupBy(p => p.ID).Select(p => new Person() { ID = p.Key, State = String.Join(",", p.Select(p2 => p2.State).ToArray()) }).ToList();
```

Comment: @tarkan: Do you use .NET 3.5? Otherwise this is less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var result = persons.GroupBy(p => p.ID)
                    .Select(g => new Person{
                        ID = g.Key,
                        State = string.Join(",", g.Select(p => p.State))
                    }).ToList();
```